How To Update Stock/Display Photos in Android Studio App Dynamically Via Cloud/AWS/Firebase
I am building a mobile app on Android Studio and Flutter. I am using AWS Amplify for S3 storage and authentication. Right now all my photos in my app are native/embedded in the code/layout. I want my photos to come from the cloud. I want to be able to change the photos periodically or add more photos to the page just like a Ticketmaster app or Amazon Music app. How can this be done?
I've set up S3 buckets and an AWS API. But i have yet to figure out or research how to make these changes dynamically like when the Amazon app updates its products photos. I am willing to use any cloud service to get this done. This would be highly appreciated.
